# Matching the identifiers with strings, digits and _

Tags: java, regex, jflex

```
[a-zA-Z]_*[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

which I'm aiming for to match :

```
astring_something;
helloall90
```

but not :

```
Astring
_helloall
```

My regex is protecting me with the identifiers should start with small case letters. But it doesn't work for `_` cases. Passing the string :

```
astring_something;
```

Is not been properly identified. Its been identified as `astring` and `something` leaving out `_`.

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: what do you want your regex to do exactly?

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you want it to start with a letter followed by zero or more letters, numbers or underscores. If so, you need to move the underscore into the second set of characters.

Change:

```
[a-zA-Z]_*[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

To:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Or, if it must start with a lowercase letter:

```
[a-z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently matching only a *single* character before an underscore.

```
[a-zA-Z]*_[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

Whether or not that's what you really want is a different issue; what about things with multiple underscores, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[a-z]+_*[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Where ...

```
^[a-z]+
```

means it must start with one or more lower case letters, followed by ...

```
_*
```

zero or more _ characters, followed by ...

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

zero or more alphanumeric characters.

This pattern will match astring_something and helloall90 but will not match _helloall and Astring